# split '\n' instead of '\\n' into string array

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I have a csv file contains columns with value `'\\\n'` and `'\\\t'` which is escaped new line and tab. However, i want to split each row into string array.

how to split specifically `'\n'` but not `'\\\n'`?

I am looking at Regex.Split is it right direction? I tried `Regex.Split(input, @"[^\\]\n");` but the result seems correct but one character in front is always missing, supposedly is caused by [^\].

Comment: Does your file contain `\r` as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *want* to use Regex.Split then `@"(?<!\\)\\n"` matches `\n` but not `\\n` (`\\\n` as well for that matter) and would not cut anything off. The negative look behind `(?<!\\)` does not form part of the match so will not remove the extra character.

Comment: glad it worked. I used this tool http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ for adhoc regex testing. Helped me to learn.

Answer (score 2):

If you're parsing a CSV file, please try to use the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) thats already in the framework. It will save you the headache of dealing with all the specific problems that come up when parsing a delimited file.

---

As mentioned below, it's part of the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`, but this comes with the framework by default, you just need a reference. And even though it's called `VisualBasic`, it's in no way VB specific.

Comment: Just to add, `TextFieldParser` is only available within the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace so that assembly has to be added to the project.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Split(input, @"[^\\]\n");
```

The problem with the regex above is that square brackets match only one character, and what they match is considered part of the match itself, meaning the character directly preceding \n will be considered part of the split string and treated accordingly.

I think what you are looking for is a negative look-behind, which is used as follows:

```
(?<!DO NOT MATCH THIS)match
```

Look-behinds and look-aheads ensure that a match exists without including the matched text as part of your match.

I assume what you are looking for is something like this:

```
Regex.Split(input, @"(?<!\\)\n");
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
(?<=^|^[^\\]|[^\\]{2})\\(n|t)
```

This will account for `\n`s and `\t`s that are at the beginning or second position of the input string